# File download link opens in new blank tab until I refresh the page

Tags: laravel

I send download link in an email in the following form:

```
https://example.com/download-file/<file-id-number>
```

In my controller I handle it like so:

```
public function download-file(Request $request)
{
    $file_id = $request->id;

    // get File model with all the parameters here (name, path, etc..)

    try {
         return Storage::disk('s3')->download($file->path, $file->name, [
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $file->name .'"',
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xlsx',
         ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // handle exceptions
}
```

I added the correct route in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('download-file/{id}', 'Files\FilesController@download-file/{id}')->name('files.download-file')
```

When I click the link it opens a blank tab in the browser with `Untitled` in the address bar, and doesn't do anything. But then if I refresh the page, the address bar suddenly shows the real link, downloads the file then the tab closes.

Also, if I click the link and the `Untitled` tab opens, then if I move to another tab in the browser then come back, the `Untitled` once again changes the to the real link

What could cause that issue? No error in the browser, I see the file id in the browser's Network tab

Comment: hover on your link on desktop browser it will display url a tiny link at bottom-left if it was correct link then inspect the link element in developer tools it might has unusual attributes  for some reason, if it not working try other browsers

Comment: It is the correct url, what do you mean unusual attributes?

Comment: some links have target="_blank" attributes that are not supported for minor version of browsers, try a different browser

Comment: Both Chrome and Edge last update do it